# Delete a row in JPA (FK)

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

Suppose I have three tables (Patients Doctors and Medicines). The Patients table has a FK contraint which references a column in the Doctors Table  and similarly the Medicines table has a FK cnstraint which references a column in the Patients table . Now when I attempt to delete from Patients  using

```
//Delete From Patient Table
    javax.persistence.Query query = manager.createQuery("DELETE  From PatientEnroll e WHERE e.no =:arg1");
    int val = Integer.parseInt(no);
    query.setParameter("arg1", val);
    query.executeUpdate();
```

I get the following error :

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`acme`.`medicines`, CONSTRAINT `PatientNo` FOREIGN KEY (`PatientNo`) REFERENCES `Patients` (`PatientNo`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

How can I delete something from the patients table ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the medicines referencing the patients first:

```
delete from Medicine m 
where m.patient.id in (select p.id from PatientEnroll p where p.no = :arg1)
```

Or disassociate them from the patients to delete:

```
update Medicine m set patient = null 
where m.patient.id in (select p.id from PatientEnroll p where p.no = :arg1)
```

Otherwise, you would obviously break a foreign key constraint: medicines referencing a non-existing patient would stay in the database. That's precisely what a foreign key constraint is useful for: avoid such inconsistencies.

Note that, unless there are hundreds of patients with a given number, the usual way of doing that with JPA is to do:

```
Patient p = getPatientByNumber(args1);
em.remove(p);
```

If you have a cascade of type REMOVE on the association, all medicines would be deleted as well. If not, you would have to do:

```
Patient p = getPatientByNumber(args1);
for (Medicine m : p.getMedicines()) {
    em.remove(m);
}
em.remove(p);
```

or

```
Patient p = getPatientByNumber(args1);
for (Medicine m : p.getMedicines()) {
    m.setPatient(null);
}
em.remove(p);
```

Comment: Patient p = getPatientByNumber(args1);
em.remove(p); Gives the same error. Since contents in the medicine table reference the Patient row

Comment: Have you read the answer? You need a cascade of type REMOVE (and not DELETE as I first wrote) on the OneToMany association for this to work.